# Neural network with float labels

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use neural networks to compute my problem. I have dataset of images and each image has label in float. Its not integer soo i canť use as **class** as in all neural networks. My float represents how old object in my image is. I have to train neural network and get output of predicted float (age). While searching the internet I didnt find any object detection neural network that would help me. I know that **loss** needs to loke like  `loss = age_true - age_predicted`. Is there network or framework that will help me with that?

Comment: You are completely overthinking the problem, its just a regression problem, not classification.

Comment: Then my problem is both. I want to classify that my object is in the picture and output its predicted age. Probadly too much complicated.

Comment: That's not complicated, its called multi-task learning.

Comment: thank you for tip, I will take look into it.